# How should I specify HTTP accept header for multipart response?

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to communicate to a HTTP endpoint that for its multipart response, I want part 1 (or reference a content-disposition filename) to be in JSON and part 2 to be in XML, what's right way to do that?

I can include both JSON and XML but then that alone doesn't communicate my intention of wanting different formats for each part.

EDIT:
Suppose I have a service and right now it's returning something along the line of:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--37adc569155a4943b203e28a422cb96f
Content-Length: ...

----37adc569155a4943b203e28a422cb96f
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: result

<Result>
    ...
</Result>

----37adc569155a4943b203e28a422cb96f
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: state

{ "Score": 42, ... }

----37adc569155a4943b203e28a422cb96f--
```

I can, and want to support passing the data back in different formats, for instance, using protocol buffer for sending the `state` back or using JSON for `result`.

I figured the right way to do it would be via the HTTP `Accept` header, but how do I communicate to the service that I want the `state` in JSON and `result` in protocol buffer? If the `Accept` header is not the way to go, what should I be using instead?

Comment: Do you mean returning a MIME multipart container from your server, and parsing it at the endpoint? Do you control both ends?

Comment: yup, I control both ends, but my client is not necessary the only one who would be using the service, and I'd like to offer the caller the flexibility to choose what format the data goes back in. I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: Have you considered `User-Agent`? It is meant to define client's capabilities, which is what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking to do is not defined by any of the RFCs and calls for using custom header fields. I would add headers like

```
X-Foo-Accept-State: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Foo-Accept-Result: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

(Where "Foo" is your company name. See elsewhere for arguments about the best way to name custom header fields.)